# jquery ajax have error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
var send = {ff_ID:"",ff_k:""};
send.ff_ID  = $(this).attr("id");
send.ff_k = $(this).find("span").text();
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/funfact_ajax",
   cache:true,
   dataType:"json",
   data:send,
   success: function(data){
     if(data.success == true){
         $(this).text(eval(send.ff_k)+1);
      }else{
        alert(data.msg);
    }
    }
});
```

problem is this line "$(this).text(eval(send.ff_k)+1);"

if i use it outside ajax , it's no problem at all ..

$(this).text("damn");

have the same error ..

here is error :

[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.createDocumentFragment')
    db (jquery-1.11.1.min.js, line 3)
    buildFragment (jquery-1.11.1.min.js, line 3)
    domManip (jquery-1.11.1.min.js, line 3)
    append (jquery-1.11.1.min.js, line 3)
    (anonymous function) (jquery-1.11.1.min.js, line 3)
    access (jquery-1.11.1.min.js, line 3)
    text (jquery-1.11.1.min.js, line 3)
    success (funfact, line 192)
    j (jquery-1.11.1.min.js, line 2)
    fireWith (jquery-1.11.1.min.js, line 2)
    x (jquery-1.11.1.min.js, line 4)
    b (jquery-1.11.1.min.js, line 4)

i have no clue what is the problem , need help , thx !

Comment: What is `send` in that code supposed to be …?

Comment: $(this).text("damn");  have the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error would probably be from `this` being a plain `Object` rather than the `Element`.

Every `function` has its own `this` value, determined when it's invoked. And, inside of the `success` callback, `this` will typically refer to the settings of the request.

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function () {
        console.log(this.type, this.url); // "POST" "/funfact_ajax"
    }
});
```

[`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) includes a `context` option to specify a different value to use, so it can refer to the `Element` there as well:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    context: this,
    success: function () {
        $(this).text(eval(send.ff_k)+1);
    }
});
```